# Is there a word for something that would be hilarious if it weren't true?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I've been thinking all day but nothing is coming to mind. I feel like I'd use it a lot if one existed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### *[tragicomic (adj), tragicomedy (n.)](http://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tragicomic)*

> *tragicomedy*
>   1) ...
>   2) ...
>   3) An incident or situation having both comic and tragic elements.
>
> *tragicomic* adj.

Edit:
My downvoter doesn't think this a fitting word. I should provide some examples, to help everyone decide for themselves.

> "In Search of Lost Time" by Marcel Proust (1913-22).
>   Proust's great novel addresses just about every problem a person can face. ... Complexity, contradiction, flux are everywhere... The only real sin here is vulgarity, which is both ridiculous and depressing--i.e., **tragicomic** and, as I see it, horribly lifelike.  http://orion.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/house.d/fivebesttragicomic.html

.

> Like the 'wanderer' in Caspar David Friedrich’s painting of 1818, Axel Antas stands in the centre of Obstructed View (Boulderstone), (Treetop) and (Cliffedge) in solitary contemplation. But in a **tragicomic** twist his views of the landscape are almost completely obscured by artificial smoke clouds that rise around his body. [REVIEW. Axel Antas, Rokeby, London](http://www.a-n.co.uk/interface/reviews/single/1199361)

.

> The **tragicomic** story of two brothers who survive by working as mechanics in a small garage in Sderot. Under the hail of missiles from Gaza, they comment the harsh reality of life in southern Israel during brotherly arguments oozing with black humour.  [a film distributor's site](http://www.jmtfilms.com/201353/HULA-AND-NATAN)

.

> Nothing in the episodes I’ve seen rivals the outlandish laugh riots of a Secret Service detail hiring Cartagena hookers... The mass-resignations, the political embarrassment, the congressional investigation — this is right in line with Vice President Meyer’s **tragicomic** milieu. [washingtonpost](http://articles.washingtonpost.com/2012-04-19/entertainment/35451690_1_vice-president-selina-meyer-veep-julia-louis-dreyfus)

.

> On the Jon Stewart show, when Obama adopted Stewart's... What we see is the **tragicomic** spectacle of the newsmedia and Democratic Party spinning the unspinnable...   [First appeared in print in The Rhinoceros Times, Greensboro, NC](http://www.ornery.org/essays/warwatch/2012-10-25-1.html)

.

> The whole situation had brought me to the verge, or nearly, of physical collapse, and I started to hear my publisher’s injunctions—the company was keeping an eye on my work—as still more noise; a noise that made me desperate, and I found it ever harder to obey. Finally, indeed, I no longer obeyed at all.
>
> The whole **tragicomic** affair found its culmination in year three: the third year of my living so absurdly in my Roman hut. My building, here again, as before in Milan, was thrown into the turmoil of renovation, for a whole pitiless year. [Anna Maria Ortese, transl. Henry Martin](http://www.archipelago.org/vol2-4/ortese.htm)

.

> We all witnessed the **tragicomic** spectacle of Western Flotillas moored within walking distance to ...
>   http://www.huffingtonpost.com/guillermo-fesser/americans-in-palestinian-_b_3052770.html

.

> "The **tragicomic** state of Arab democracy"
>   Abdeljabbar Adwan
>   The state of democracy in the Arab world is a tragicomedy. It would be funny if it weren’t so sad.   [Lebanonwire](http://lebanonwire.com/0212/02121419DS.asp)

.

> —A Blog Devoted to Exposing America's Most Powerful Cult Leader and Political Power Broker—
>
> "This Would Be Funny if It Weren't True"
>   I have come across information about the **tragicomic** life of former Bush appointee... Here's a passage from an 1988 article... :
>   ... in which they literally prostrate themselves on the floor before a picture of Moon...  [blog](http://realsunmyungmoon.blogspot.com/2006/02/tragicomedic-career-of-former-bush.html)

.

> I guess on one **tragicomic** level, at least those jerk-off blog people are honest about their intentions?  [blog](http://be-bopz.tumblr.com/)

.

> I think it’s **tragicomic** that these actors (stevens and brown-findlay) think that they still have the support of the fans after ruining the show. Well, they don’t. [tvline](http://tvline.com/2012/12/10/downton-abbey-season-4-spoilers-dan-stevens-leaving/)

[Edit2: noun & adjective separation, definition reformat]

Comment: Good word, but could you please link to the definition you used, improve the formatting, and add some commentary on why it's a good choice?

Comment: +1 and the state of it is called *tragicomedy*, mentioned in one of your examples. E.g., “*Dr Horrible’s Sing-along Blog* is (a) tragicomedy”.

Comment: @JonPurdy Thank you for that comment! It compelled me to make constructive changes.

Answer (score 1):

I think a word that could be used in a lot of cases would be **ridiculous**.  It can take on the meaning of funny and could also mean absurd.

Comment: How does this capture the sense of “if it weren't true”?

Comment: When true it would be an object of ridicule.

Answer (score 1):

The answer, I believe, is no; there is no single word (in English) that fully and precisely means something that would be hilarious if it were not true.

A few possibilities not yet mentioned that may fit your intended usage:

ironic

farcical

fantastic(-al)

outlandish

bizarre

deadpan

wry

dark

Answer (score 0):

This seems to fit the notion of 'black humour' very well, but I don't think a single word encapsulates that idea.

Answer (score -3):

I will go with the adjective [*sarcastic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sarcastic).