# Adjective for a situation that is so depressing that it can make you laugh?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, adjectives

What is the proper adjective that describes a situation that is so depressing that it can make you laugh as well?

Comment: Please edit your question in accordance with the guidelines for [single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). You should give an example sentence, describe any additional nuances of meaning that you want the requested word to have, and explain any research you have done (are there any verbs you have already considered, but discarded? Did you check a thesaurus?).

Comment: possible duplicate: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/128934/is-there-a-word-for-something-that-would-be-hilarious-if-it-werent-true

http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55839/word-for-something-sad-and-funny-at-the-same-time

Comment: Vote to close because of two possible duplicates which the OP should check out and then modify his Q from what he learns from them.    We now have 3 Qs with overlapping answers, none of which really click.

Answer (score 1):

The word I would use would be "tragicomic" or "tragicomical."  Both are adjectives that describe the combined elements of tragedy and comedy.

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tragicomic